# Powershell select filenames that match

Tags: powershell

List all filenames that match a pattern but can't seem to get it to list only the files I need I am eventually going to replace the filter with user input

```
$src = $env:ININ_TRACE_ROOT
$cmp = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$dst = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop\" +  $cmp

$lDate = Read-Host "Which Date?"
$s2 = $src + "\$ldate\"
$filter = "ip"
Get-ChildItem -Path $s2 | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $filter } | Select Name
```

Tried the above problem is it returns

```
accserver.zip                                                                                                          
acdserver.zip                                                                                                          
adminserver.zip                                                                                                        
adminserver_1.zip                                                                                                      
caasbillingserver.zip                                                                                                  
caasproxyserver.zip                                                                                                    
CallLog.zip                                                                                                            
clientservices.zip                                                                                                     
ClientStatsWkgQDataLog.zip                                                                                             
compressormanager.zip                                                                                                  
datamanager.zip                                                                                                        
dsserver.zip                                                                                                           
fbmc.zip                                                                                                               
hostserver.zip                                                                                                         
httppluginhost.zip                                                                                                     
i3runcrreport.zip                                                                                                      
i3runcrreport_1.zip                                                                                                    
i3runcrreport_2.zip                                                                                                    
i3runcrreport_3.zip                                                                                                    
imapconnector.zip                                                                                                      
ininfaxserver.zip                                                                                                      
interactionclient.zip                                                                                                  
interactionrecoveryu.zip                                                                                               
ip.ininlog_journal                                                                                                     
ip.zip                                                                                                                 
ipdbserver.ininlog_journal                                                                                             
ipdbserver.zip                                                                                                         
ipserver.ininlog_journal                                                                                               
ipserver.zip                                                                                                           
ip_1.zip                                                                                                               
ip_10.zip                                                                                                              
ip_11.zip                                                                                                              
ip_12.zip                                                                                                              
ip_13.zip                                                                                                              
ip_14.zip                                                                                                              
ip_2.zip                                                                                                               
ip_3.zip                                                                                                               
ip_4.zip                                                                                                               
ip_5.zip                                                                                                               
ip_6.zip                                                                                                               
ip_7.zip                                                                                                               
ip_8.zip                                                                                                               
ip_9.zip                                                                                                               
iwpserver.zip                                                                                                          
LineGroupStatsDataLog.zip                                                                                              
mail account monitor.zip                                                                                               
mrcpsubsystem.zip                                                                                                      
notifier.zip                                                                                                           
notifierserver.zip                                                                                                     
notifier_1.zip                                                                                                         
notifier_2.zip                                                                                                         
notifier_3.zip                                                                                                         
optimizer server.zip                                                                                                   
OutOfProcCustomDLL.zip
postofficeserver.zip                                                                                                   
processautomationserver.zip                                                                                            
promptserver.zip                                                                                                       
provisionserver.zip                                                                                                    
QueuePeriodAgentStatsDataLog.zip                                                                                       
QueuePeriodWorkgroupStatsDataLog.zip                                                                                   
queuestatprovider.zip                                                                                                  
recorder server.zip                                                                                                    
RecoSubsystem.zip                                                                                                      
remocoserver.zip                                                                                                       
rstrapmonitor.zip                                                                                                      
sessionmanager.zip                                                                                                     
SIPEngine-mrcp.ininlog_journal                                                                                         
SIPEngine-mrcp.zip                                                                                                     
SIPEngine.ininlog_journal                                                                                              
SIPEngine.zip                                                                                                          
smsserver.zip                                                                                                          
smtpconnector.zip                                                                                                      
SNMPAgent.zip                                                                                                          
statalertserver.zip                                                                                                    
statserveragent.zip                                                                                                    
statserveragent_1.zip                                                                                                  
statserveragent_2.zip                                                                                                  
statserverworkgroup.zip                                                                                                
statserverworkgroup_1.zip                                                                                              
statserverworkgroup_2.zip                                                                                              
surveyservice.zip                                                                                                      
switchover.zip                                                                                                         
switchoverfilemonitor.zip                                                                                              
tracker server.zip                                                                                                     
tracker server_1.zip                                                                                                   
transactionserver.zip                                                                                                  
transactionserver_1.zip                                                                                                
transactionserver_2.zip                                                                                                
transactionserver_3.zip                                                                                                
transactionserver_4.zip                                                                                                
tsserver.zip                                                                                                           
tsserver_1.zip                                                                                                         
tsserver_2.zip                                                                                                         
tsserver_3.zip                                                                                                         
voicexml host server.zip
```

Problem is I need it to only return

```
ip.zip
ip_1.zip                                                                                                               
ip_10.zip                                                                                                              
ip_11.zip                                                                                                              
ip_12.zip                                                                                                              
ip_13.zip                                                                                                              
ip_14.zip                                                                                                              
ip_2.zip                                                                                                               
ip_3.zip                                                                                                               
ip_4.zip                                                                                                               
ip_5.zip                                                                                                               
ip_6.zip                                                                                                               
ip_7.zip                                                                                                               
ip_8.zip                                                                                                               
ip_9.zip
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this

Updated using this now returns the list but is there a better way to do it?

```
$filter = "^ip[^server][^db][^ininlog_journal]"
```

Also this works but missing the non ip.zip

```
$filter = "^ip_[0-9]"
```

Comment: As Bill_Stewart stated what you want to match against is `'^ip'` which is a Regular Expression (commonly referred to as RegEx). The carat character (^) specifies the beginning of the string or line, so this will match anything that begins with the text "ip". The issue you are seeing is that you then go on to specify an underscore followed by a number. If you take off the "_[0-9]" portion of your filter it should work fine. The key here was the carat character, forcing the "ip" match to be at the beginning of the line so it wouldn't match the ip in .zip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `-match` uses a regular expression, you should be able to write something like this:

```
get-childitem $s2 | where-object { $_.Name -match '^ip' }
```

(i.e., match when the Name property starts with `ip`).

See the `about_Regular_Expressions` help topic for more information.